# No /etc/init.d/sshd file? (Ubuntu / EC2)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, amazon-ec2

On a fresh EC2 instance running Ubuntu, I see that there's no /etc/init.d/sshd file. I tried

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And it shows that openssh-server is already the newest version. How do I get the /etc/init.d/sshd file?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is now using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com) to do the `init` and `/etc/init.d/` job. Instead of writing `/etc/init.d/sshd $ACTION` you are now supposed to write `service ssh restart` or just `restart ssh`. Note that it is called `ssh`, not `sshd`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. The sshd in not present in ubuntu 14.04 server, i ran sudo service ssh restart and it work.

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu installation it's `/etc/init.d/ssh`

Try

```
dpkg -L openssh-server | grep init.d
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they switched the ssh service over to Upstart config files. Look in `/etc/init/`.